# Select Query doesn't show any results and appears to hang

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table, dbo.PE, in SQL Server 2017.  Yesterday I had over 40,000 records.  today when I do this:

```
Select Top 1000 * From dbo.PE
```

Nothing happens.  No results (not even a No records message).  It just sits there and spins and says Executing Query until it is cancelled.  Any Idea to what is going on?  I tried inserting new data and once again, nothing happens, just sits there and spins until cancelled.

I can access other tables in the database, just not this one. No permissions have been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, To answer this question, gsharp was correct in that the table was locked.  I ran the following statement to kill the session (https://infrastructureland.wordpress.com/2015/01/24/how-to-release-or-remove-lock-on-a-table-sql-server/):

```
SELECT    
    OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) AS TableName,    
    Resource_type,    
    request_session_id    
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks L    
JOIN sys.partitions P ON L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id    
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) = ‘dbo.PE’
```

Found out that the session ID was 54 so I executed:

```
kill 54
```